# Running Tabs from java code not XML

Tags: java, android, xml, view, tabs

What I have right now is 4 tabs, one of them has a custom view and some widgets on it. In order for that whole thing to work I need to start the activity `Tab3Activity` and then it runs correctly (I know this because I have set the default activity to that in the manifest) but what I have right now is the tabs run from xml files... this is what I have.

```
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag0");
        specs.setContent(R.id.connecttionTab);
        specs.setIndicator("Connection Tab");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Zone Manager");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_vaccontrol));
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Graphical Layout");
        th.addTab(specs);
```

this is the activity that needs to be started for this tab to work correctly...

```
public class Tab3Activity extends Activity 
{
    private Tab3 mTab3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab3);
        mTab3 = (Tab3) findViewById(R.id.tab3_display);
    }

    public void onAddZone(View view)
    {
        mTab3.addZone();
    }

}
```

how do I start this tab from a java file such as that but the rest of them stay starting from XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign an intent for the activity that you want to launch to each tab, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3Activity.class);
TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab3").setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

This is what I use in my main activity where I have tabs.

Comment: When I do that, Tab3Activity just goes over top of all the other xml and is there on every tab, does that make scene?

Comment: Are you setting intents for each of the tabs? It might help if you uploaded a screenshot of what it looks like now.

Comment: No, I am only using intent for the one, the rest xml

Comment: because I want the most of the tabs all running from the same java file.